# Clear checkboxes with button

Tags: angular

Using Angular 5, I built a selection form with an ngModel of `doc.selected`. When the user hits a clear button, I'd like all `doc.selected` checkboxes to uncheck.

```
<button (click)="clear()">Clear Selected</button>

<table>
  <tr>
    .....
  </tr>

  <tr *ngFor="let doc of docs">
    <td><input type="checkbox" [(ngModel)]="doc.selected" (change)="select(doc.ID, doc.selected)"></td>
    <td>{{doc.DocumentGroup}}</td>
    <td>{{doc.Title}}</td>
    <td>{{doc.Description}}</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

My clear function that is not working correctly:

```
  clear(selected) {
    selected == false;
  }
```

How can I do this?

Comment: `clear() { for (let doc of this.docs) { doc.selected = false; } }`

Answer (score 0):

You would have to get the selected checkboxes and make them false.

Ex:

```
var element = <HTMLInputElement> document.getElementById("is3dCheckBox");
var isChecked = element.checked;
```

once you see if it the `element.checked` is true. all you have to do is make it false so it can uncheck the checkboxes. Please be advised this is just a sample. There are many ways to do it and easier too